# Hide the ugly startup screen (dojox not fully parsed yet)

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

When I start my application, the dojo start loading but are not yet fully parsed and thus screen looks ugly!!!

Is there a way to hide this ugly screen until it is fully loaded a parsed?

Thanks
Dominique

---

**EDIT ADD SNIPPET**
I heard that WL Studio would hide automatically the body and thus no need to create an overlay.

Here my html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Test.css">
<script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false"
    src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <div id="main" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View"
        data-dojo-props='selected:true'>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
            data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>Main Screen</div>
        <button id="refreshBte" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button"
            style="width: 100%">Refresh</button>
        <button id="settingsBte" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button"
            style="width: 100%">Setting</button>
    </div>
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Test.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my js

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    require([ "dojo/core-web-layer", "dojo/mobile-ui-layer",
            "dojo/mobile-compat-layer" ], dojoInit);

}

function dojoInit() {
    require([ "dojo", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/compat",
            "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme", "dojox/mobile/Heading", "dojox/mobile/Button" ],
            function(dojo) {
                dojo.ready(function() {
                });
            });
}
```

I tried also to add hidden="hidden" in the  but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is,

you need to build a loading overlay. Check out this tutorial:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/loading_overlay/

Comment: I got the message "dojo is not defined". Added the code above.

Comment: When I add the code in your answer, I got a message that it has to be reviewed by peer before be shown.

Comment: i can not help you on every step, you have to read something about using dojo. the "dojo is not defined" error comes up when you do not use the require function to get a reference to dojo...

Comment: I tried many ways and read a lot of different articles about creating an overlay but didn't succeed.
Does somebody has a example for Worklight?
Thx

Comment: Add snippet (see above), any clue?
Many Thanks
Dominique

Comment: sorry but i havent heard of wl studio, you should ask a new question and include the tag WL Studio. it is very hard for me to reproduce the scenario you have. if you really want an answer, you should make it as easy as possible, for example by implementing a jsfiddle that shows your problem. if you do not do that, each person has to implement your scenario for himself / herself = time consuming...

Comment: Thanks Lucian, WL Studio is Worklight Studio and I already added the tag ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What I normally did with this is:

```
<div id="main" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

After the parsing is complete:
set the main visibility to visible again.

Might not fully solve the problem (depends on how fast the browser able to resolve the layout), but you won't be getting plain html displayed until it is:converted into widget.

Further reference:
dojo/Ready = to detect when the page is parsed.